# Automatically start countdown Xcode XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a button that takes me to another view controller and automatically starts a countdown from 3 to 0, but i don't know how to set the countdown on the other view controller. Here's the code i tried:

```
@implementation TestViewController

-(IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    CountdownViewController *cdvc = [[CountdownViewController alloc]  
initWithNibName:@"CountViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cdvc animated:YES];
}

@implementation CountdownViewController

int maintInt = 3;
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)countDown {
    maintInt -= 1;
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", maintInt];
    if(maintInt==1){
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems OK to me. what is exactly the problem you're having?

Comment: in countdown view controller actually it says undeclared identifier self. i think i should add the int and nstimer somewhere else but i don't know where.

Comment: Is the error on the line `int maintInt = 3;`? Because if it is, you can't just add code outside of your methods like that.

Comment: You can place it in the init method of the CountDown controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to place your countdown code in a method, which you should call in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` method regarding your needs.

```
@implementation TestViewController

-(IBAction)test:(id)sender {
    CountdownViewController *cdvc = [[CountdownViewController alloc]  
initWithNibName:@"CountViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cdvc animated:YES];
}

@end

@implementation CountdownViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // .. customize your views here ..

    // Initialize the timer once your view has been loaded.
    //
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


static int maintInt = 3;

- (void)countDown:(NSTimer *)timer {
    count.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", maintInt];
    maintInt -= 1;

    if (maintInt == 0 && timer) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
}

@end
```